# How to call Python function in PHP passing variable argument

Tags: php, python, exec

I'm calling the function using 'exec' and defining the argument as a variable.

```
$jsonrequest = escapeshellarg(json_encode($request, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK));
$solveroutput = exec('sudo python /var/www/website.com/services/run.py $jsonrequest');
```

I have already  tried to call like this:

```
$solveroutput = exec("sudo python /var/www/website.com/services/run.py '$jsonrequest'");
```

and

```
$solveroutput = exec("sudo python /var/www/website.com/services/run.py $jsonrequest");
```

and also without 'sudo'

When I call the function directly in command line in the server (AWS), I receive the result, as following. `$jsonrequest` above is exactly the way I'm typing in command line.

```
[lsenna@ip ~]$ sudo python /var/www/website.com/services/run.py '{"max_split":4,"order":681,"max_cost_frac":0.1,"items":[{"productid":8745,"qty":1,"estimatedprice":53.6}],"bids":[{"vendorid":1,"minimum_order":0,"items":[{"productid":8745,"qty":1,"estimatedprice":100}]}]}'
```

RESPONSE:

```
{"status": "OK", "order": 681, "deliveries": [{"vendorid": 1, "productid": 8745}]}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways would to use an application router like Crossbar.io and a protocol like WAMP (Web Apps Messaging Protocol) etc. Your Python function can be a publisher and your PHP function can be a subscriber. This method is not recommended for beginners as it requires a fair bit of programming experience.